# DynamoDB: Is it worth indexing a table for a one-time migration effort?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We are migrating a ton of different tables with different attributes to another table using a script to do conversions into the new DynamoDB table formats.

Details aside, we need to add the "migrated" attribute to every item in the old tables. In order to do this, we are aware that we need to do a scan & update every item in the table with the new attribute. However, if the script we're running that adds this attribute dies midway, we will need to restart the script and filter out anything that doesn't have this new attribute (and only add the new attribute to the items missing it).

One thought that came up was that we could add a global secondary index onto the table with the primaryKey + the migrated flag so that we could just use that to identify what needs to get migrated faster.

However, for a one-time migration effort (that might be run a few times in the case of failures), I'm not sure if its worth the cost of creating the index? The table has hundreds of millions of items in it, and it's hard for me to justify creating a huge index just to speed up the scan. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked into using AWS Database Migration Service for this task? It automatically manages the migration workers, and will take care of any failures/retries so that you don’t need to worry about it.

Comment: @MatthewPope Yes- unfortunately, we can't use the migration service for our use case because instead of writing from one table directly into another, we have to go through some APIs our service uses for ingestion and auditing.

Comment: You could avoid needing the index by using DMS to extract everything to essentially a `tmp` bucket in S3, and then apply a custom solution to send it from S3 to your ingestion API. Once a S3 file is successfully loaded to the new table, delete it from S3 so that it won’t be processed again. There are a few more things you could add to make it more fault tolerant, but it would be too fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To use a GSI effectively you would ideally make it a sparse index. It would only contain unmigrated items. You would control this by setting an attribute "unmigrated" on every item, then remove that from the item after migrating it, but this will 4x your writes (because you write to the table and index, once when you add the unmigrated flag, once when you remove it).

I recommend that in your script that scans the table, periodically save the LastEvaluatedKey so you can resume where it left off if the script fails. To speed up the scan you can perform a segmented scan in parallel.